# message error :"Cannot read property 'getSheetByName' of nul (ligne 4, fichier "code")

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all, it is the first time for my work about the electronic signature to put in the GMAIL (in html). I created the simple html and put it in gmail. It works well

And now, my goal is to extract the data like last name, first name and profession (in function of the profil  as account google) to put them in HTML and then, in gmail (signature parameter).
As I don't know anything about javascript etc ..., I followed in the youtube to understand how it works (see the link : "").
I received an error message "cannot read property (getSheetByName 'of null". It seems to me that the table is empty. so, I add a part with the "if" for the empty case . It still doesn't work.

Could you help me fix the error?

Thank you in advance to help me please.

Sincerely

B.Delcroix from Toulouse, France

### **my procedures, see below.**

google app script :

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('benevoles');
  if (ws != null) {
  Logger.log(ws.getIndex());
}
 const h1 = ws.getRange("B3").getValue();
  const subheader = ws.getRange("B4").getValue();
  const headers = ws.getRange("B6;E6").getValues();
  const initiale = headers[0][0];
  const name = headers[0][1];
  const prenom = headers[0][2];
  const profession = headers[0][3];

  const lr = ws.getLastRow();
  const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(7,2,lr-7,4).getValues();

  const totalLine = ws.getRange(lr,2,1,4).getValues();
  const totalTexte = totalLine[0][0];
  const totalCount = totalLine[0][3];

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("mail");

  htmlTemplate.h1 = h1;

   htmlTemplate.subheader  = subheader ;
   htmlTemplate.headers = headers;
   htmlTemplate.initiale = initiale;
   htmlTemplate.name = name;
  
   htmlTemplate.totalTexte  = totalTexte ;
   htmlTemplate.totalCount = totalCount;
   htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues  = tableRangeValues ;

  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

  console.log(htmlForEmail);

  GmailApp.SendEmail(
     "xxxxxxx@xxxx.com",
     "test envoi mail html",
     "svp, ouvrez ce mail avec ce support client HTML",
     {htmlbody : htmlForEmail});
}
```

---

HTML

```
<!DOC TYPE html>
<html>
  <Head>
    <base target="_top">
  </Head>
  <body>
    <div><div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <h1> <?= h1 ?></h1>
          <div> <?= subheader ?></div>
          <div></div>
           <Table>
           <Thead>
           <tr><th>initiale</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>prenom</th>
              <th>profession</th></tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
              <td>
              Col1 d1
              </td>
              <td>
              Col2 d2
              </td>
              <td>
              Col3 d3
              </td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
           <tfoot>
             <tr>
              <td>
              <?= totalTexte ?>
              </td>
              <td>
           
              </td>
              <td>
              <?= totalCount ?>
              </td>
           </tr>
           </tfoot>
           </Table>
       </div>
       <div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your error means that you are using a [Standalone Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) opposed to a [Container-bound Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)

You are using the method `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` but there is no active spreadsheet if your script is not bound to any!

To bind a script to a spreadsheet:

- Open the spreadshee tof interest
- Go on Tools -> Script Editor
- Paste your script and save it

Alternatively, if you prefer to use a Standalone script, replace the line

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

by

`SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)`

Whereby `id` should be replaced by the actual Id of the spreadsheet you want to work with - otherwise the script does not know to which spreadsheet you refer.